# How I can show zero ratio?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a small problem, I don't know how to solve it
appreciate if anyone can help me

I'm calculating the Ratio for specific grades (Not All grades) as below

```
Select Term, GRADE,
       count (*) as "Total",
       case
       when GRADE IN ('A+','B+','C+','F') then
       round(100* RATIO_TO_Report(count(*))over (partition by Term),2)
else 0
       end as "Precentage "
  from RESULTS
 where Term = ‘2021’
       and GRADE IN('A+','B+','C+','F')
order by case
when GRADE IN('A+') then 1
when GRADE IN('B+') then 2
when GRADE IN('C+') then 3
when GRADE IN('F') then 4
else 5
end
```

I have tried to use the  below function but still I'm not getting the 0

```
COALESCE(count (GRADE),0)
```

my sql is working fine no issues, I only need to show if the count is 0 for one of the grades then the ratio is 0

The desired output as below, the C+ row is not showing because of the zero count. How can I show the zero?

[image]

I don't know how to do it

Thank you all

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.  Given that `count()` never returns `0`, `coalesce()` is useless on it.

Comment: Did you try something like 
`case when exists (select * from (values ('A+'),('B+'),('C+'),('F')) as x(grade) left join Results r on x.grade = r.grade where term = '2021' and fr.grade is null) then 0`?
If your database has no `values` clause try 
`(select 'A+' grade union all select 'B+' union all select 'C+' union all select 'F') x` instead.

Comment: Note that when GordonLinoff says "count() never returns zero" he probably means "in this particular query"; `count(*)` counts rows and doesn't return 0. `count(somecolumn)` might return zero if the column is full of nulls. Your GRADE column cannot contain any nulls because you specify the values it must contain. As to your actual problem, it sounds like you might want `CASE WHEN count(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ... `

Comment: I did tried the case when but still not showing the zero @Caius Jard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you mean your table doesn't have any C+ entries - well you can't count them then, because they aren't there to count

Let's simplify the query a bit:

```
select 
  term, 
  grade,
  round(100 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by term),2) as Percentage
from results
where term = '2021' and grade IN ('A+','B+','C+','F')
group by term, grade
```

..which will just have rows for A, B and F

Then let's left join it to a query that definitely produces all the rows you want:

```
with res as (
 select 
  term, 
  grade,
  round(100 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by term),2) as Percentage
 from results
 where term = '2021' --we can remove the grades from here because specifying them below will restrict to just those grades
 group by term, grade
)

select
  *
from
  (select 'A+' grade from dual union select 'B+' from dual union select 'C+' from dual union select 'F' from dual) grades
  LEFT JOIN res ON grades.grade = res.grade
```

*Now* you will have a null for C+ that you can coalesce ;)